# c++) I tried to open cmd file in YOLO but it is denied

Tags: c++, windows, cmd, yolo

I started my term project using YOLO.

So I bulit YOLO and got cmd files for using YOLO.

for test, I tried opening one of this files in VS17 by using c++.

this is my source

```
#include <windows.h>

int main() {

    system("start C:\\darknet_master\\build\\darknet\\x64\\darknet_coco.cmd");

    return 0;
}
```

if i open this file in diretory then it woks very well.

Even i can detect someting by file path.

But if i open this file in VS17 then it does not.

what can i do?

And is it best way for using YOLO in my project??

if there are much better way then please let me know T__T

Comment: Check your working directory. It would be different in VS17.

Comment: could tell me more??

Comment: done. i moved files under my solution diretory. then it will be worked